# Used Canon 5D Mark II - Alternate model to upgrade to full frame?

Tags: canon, photography-basics, canon-5d-mark-ii

My boy is insistent on getting a Canon 5D Mark II used on Craigslist. He said he has to shoot "full frame". He said it has to be Canon.

He's looking at spending $900-$1,000. He want's a Canon 5D Mark III, but said the Mark II is good value. Is this a good camera for him to shoot "full frame" or is there an alternate full frame model?

Update: Thanks for the replies. He been shooting with a Rebel for a few years and has a few lenses so he said it smarter to stay with Canon. My concern is if his money can be spent on an alternate Canon model...

Comment: "He said he has to shoot "full frame". He said it has to be Canon." Have you determined where these requirements are coming from? It's generally untrue that a beginner *needs* full frame.

Comment: "He's looking at spending $900-$1,000" Is this for a body only, or body and a lens?

Comment: Your update explains the brand choice, which is reasonable. It does not explain the wish for full frame, though. What is the desired improvement over the rebel? What change is a full frame camera supposedly going to make for him? Also: "*and has a few lenses*" which lenses exactly? Not all canon lenses are compatible with full frame camera.

Comment: If he has cropped lenses for his Rebel then they won't work on full frame.  You could look into a newer crop frame camera.  Such as 80D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good camera, but if he intends to shoot sport or any other fast action, I would suggest that he looks elsewhere. This camera has pretty mediocre AF system.

Comment: Thank you MirekE. Great answer. This is what he needs to know before he buys.

Comment: I'd suggest the 6D instead.  For only slightly more money, that gives you a better center focus point, much better low-light image quality, GPS, and Wi-Fi.  The same caveats about the AF system apply, though; the 6D uses basically the same AF as the 5D Mark II, IIRC.  It's usable for sports, but it isn't wonderful.  :-)